# Best way to let people know you aren't dead, just taking pictures?

Tags: macro, shooting-technique, tips

First of all, sorry if this question is off-topic - I have looked at the help section and I believe this falls into the "techniques and best practices" category, and [similar questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/110828/37704) have been asked before, but I'm still open to suggestions about editing, moving or closing this question.

---

My wife loves macrophotography and can often be found alone, lying on her stomach in a field of grass or in a forest taking pictures of a flower, mushroom or insect for hours without any noticeable movement. This is fine and well, but sometimes one or more random passersby come up to check up on her: to see if she requires medical assistance.

She is already used to this and just tells them she's okay, but still feels bad for needlessly worrying those people, not to mention that the next time they see someone lying still, the same people might not check up on someone who is in genuine distress.

What would be the best way to let laypeople know that the motionless, prone person is, in fact, taking pictures and needs no assistance? Preferably this method would

- work from a distance and
- not involve lugging around and setting up heavy or bulky equipment (like a meter-wide banner saying "TAKING PICTURES"),
- nor involve sounds or movement that might scare away the animal being photographed (mouse, bird, insect, etc.).

Comment: At least these aren't voyeurs thinking she is shooting people making out in the bushes (true story...)

Comment: How about lying on a towel or blanket? People do that in parks, meadows and beaches all the time.

Comment: Is her camera not visible?

Comment: How about also not preventing someone eventually checking if she *does* actually have a physical/medical problem while lying in the grass shooting macro?

Comment: @ZeissIkon that's actually a really good point, thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: Is it inappropriate to note that your wife is *lying* on her stomach?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thanks for pointing it out! I did consider this disctinction, but apparently I was wrong about it. Is it better now?

Comment: @Acccumulation From more than a few paces, facing away from the path, in non-negligible vegetation it is usually not.

Comment: Not a real answer (since obviously she would like a way for people to know this when she is photographing alone) but you could tag along with her sitting several paces away with your own camera (on a tripod so you don't get tired) trained on her.

Comment: I read the title as "Best way to prove to people you're still alive, just *by* taking pictures". But the body makes it clear that the correct interpretation is: "Best way to let people know you aren't dead, *but rather* just taking pictures".

Comment: Is using a remote controlled screen an option? Your wife could sit on a chair and interact with her DSLR via a mobile app, which is a lot more convenient. Just a bit of out of the box thinking.

Comment: @JonathanReez Sorry, but not an option at all. Most of her nature macrophotography workflow consists of careful positioning of the equipment and the subject, which is impossible via a mobile app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A blanket or equivalent, as suggested in the comments, looks like the best solution to me.

Comment: It will be considered, but I guess it will be summarily rejected, as space is at a premium in a camera bag, with all the lenses, batteries, flashes, reflectors and so on. But if the blanket could be fitted to the outside of the bag, it wouldn't soil the precious equipment with leaves, twigs, bugs and dirt either. Hmm...

Comment: @zovits I think I have seen rescue blankets which are extremely thin. Might be something to look in to.

Comment: Rather than the flimsy rescue blankets suggested by @Prof.Falken's comment, a lightweight tarp would be good.  I've got a couple that are drab green on one side, silver on the other, thus doubling as a reflector and camouflage (actual camo pattern also available).  My smaller one is something like 2.4x1.2m (8'x4'), costs next to nothing on eBay, and folds into a pouch less than half the size of my flash.  You may be able to get a 6' version.  Something like [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Waterproof-Large-Lightweight-Camping-Tent-Tarp-Shelter-Hammock-Rain-Fly-Cover-UK/353196341267)

Comment: In the end this is the solution that got implemented: a multiple square meter piece of thin, almost transparent plastic film originally intended as protective covering for internal painting work was bought and suitable sizes are cut so that multiple plies can be used to provide both protection from both moisture and dirt and to serve as a sign of intention towards onlookers. If the subsequent real-world usage results in another approach being tried, I'll update the Q&A accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

While this is a rare instance of need, it's a shame there isn't a photographic equivalent of the red field with white diagonal stripe "diver down" flag, or the more internationally-recognized blue-and-white "Alpha" flag.

Perhaps she could fashion her own "photographer in action" sign, with a combination of symbols for instant recognition (a finger in front of lips, meaning "shhhh"/quiet, and a camera), with words saying a photographer is trying to shoot skittish wildlife closeup, staying still and quiet. That should be enough for people to leave her alone. A couple of those signs placed 10–50 yards away, from the most anticipated approach locations, should be enough to at least reduce the amount of well-intended interlopers.

The sign probably only needs to be about 20" by 15", maybe smaller. It can be foldable, or depending on you or your wife's craftiness, could be rollable, or even printed on fabric or lightweight tent material.

The support could be a telescoping pole for easy transport, or perhaps a lightweight inexpensive tripod for easy setup.

Comment: Maybe the lightweight tripod is enough of a prop -- I think people would recognize one as a tool photographers use.

Comment: @KyleMiller perhaps, but a tripod by itself, with a prone and unmoving photographer nearby, doesn't explain the situation. Seems to me it could be easily be mistaken for a photographer who fell unconscious, in need of help, begetting a situation _à la_ the original question... bringing us back to other solutions.

Comment: I was going to post something similar, suggesting a "do not disturb my subject" aspect.  I think a sign is helpful, though I like the other answer's suggestion of appropriately personalised kit.  I faced something similar in first aid training recently - we were training outdoors partly because of the virus  and a little too easily seen from the road

Comment: Universal? Wikipedia says that flag is only in the US, and the one used universally is half blue half white...

Comment: @user253751 Noted, edited.

Comment: This was my first idea as well, but I wanted to get ideas and feedback from people with more experience with the same situation. Now, on to find some solution that is both light and compact, and visible enough.

Comment: @zovits I'd probably use a [lightweight light stand](https://www.amazon.com/Emart-Photography-Compact-Light-Stand/dp/B079996P1F). I think maybe a high-visibility orange flag, similar to a sports lineman judge flag, mounted on top would work great. If you're feeling crafty, maybe sew in a top-bar into the flag so it always stands unfurled (like the US flags used in the Apollo moon program)

Comment: The stand is a great idea as well, but actually I'm thinking of using a children's bicycle safety flag, like [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B074CXLVF1/?coliid=I3M43WG0I13HA6&colid=33KQ9ZXR7GMYF&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) as it is lightweight, foldable and can be DIYed to have a stake on the bottom instead of a mounting plate. Maybe with a custom print on the flag part.

Comment: @zovits That's an excellent idea!

Answer (score 18):

Scootbb has a great answer, but I would suggest that you have some custom shirts, hoodies or jackets made for her with wording on the back. *Bonus points for you if you give them to her as a gift.*

On the back it could say "I am not dead or injured, just taking photos"   or any wording you feel is appropriate.

This may preferable to carrying a sign.

You could have the phrase "Macro photographer at work" with any of the following  humorous wording suggestions below it:

- Not dead yet, but [grateful](https://coreanavn.shop/products/im-not-dead-yet-but-im-grateful-for-grateful-dead-fan-t-shirt/).
- I am communing with nature.
- Naps are good.
- I ❤️ worms.
- My husband thinks I'm a doormat.
- Can you hand me that lens?
- Can you smell that?
- I know that earring is here somewhere.

(*feel free to add your own suggestions*)

Comment: But what is the difference between a live person wearing such a hoodie and a dead person wearing such a hoodie?   I suspect that a concerned person is not going to look at a potential corpse wearing a marked hoodie and then thinking "Oh, that must be a a photographer at work, I better not disturb them".

Comment: Great suggestion, and probably the place to start with, over signs per my answer. Certainly easier and more portable than mine! =)

Comment: @PeterM perhaps a shirt/hoodie, in combination with a sign right next to her saying "no really, I mean it, I'm alive. Read my shirt" would convince most well meaning people. =)

Comment: I'm imagining a serial killer, with a stock of such hoodies, in which they clothe their victims after killing them.

Comment: How about "The reports of my death are greatly exaggerated"?

Comment: @PeterM are you saying that you think  that somebody is going to know they are going to be dead so they put on the shirt and then go lay down and  become dead?  Or they somehow know that someone else is going to make them dead so they put the shirt on to avoid there body being disturbed?  These things had not occurred to me but since you point it  out perhaps it is food for thought.“Bring out yet dead“

Comment: @AlaskaMan No, I'm saying that if a bystander is concerned enough to actually check on some prone person to see if they need help and/or aren't dying, then that bystander is not really going to stop to pay attention to some pithy slogan written written upon the clothing of said prone person.  Especially if the bystander is trained in first aid because they know that someone lying prone for no visible reason for an extended period may be in trouble.  IMHO you'd be better off with a comically large fake old time movie camera as a prop to imply that something unusual is going on.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Also especially as in order to read said pithy slogan you're already going to have be so close to the prone person (because the writing is not on a plane easily seen from a distance) that by the time you have read it, you've already interrupted the prone person simply by your presence. (I'd get really nervous if I was taking macro pics  of a subject in teh ground and someone was hovering over me, but out of my vision)

Comment: Nobody had "I ATE'NT DEAD" yet?

Comment: And what if she actually does die while she's taking pictures?

Comment: @Acccumulation, probably the same as if that happens when no-one else is near enough to see.  It's a risk we all take.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.  It might not stop people asking the question, but it may well reduce the embarrassment/awkwardness of the situation, and that's the objective.

Comment: These are great (and funny!) suggestions, but it would be quite hard to find a typographical solution that can be read from the typical distances involved. Another difficulty would be finding a piece of clothing that can be worn as the outermost layer in all possible weather conditions, from sweltering summer to freezing winter. (Yes, it looks like all months are great for nature macrophotography, if the artist is determined enough.)

Comment: @zovits A lightweight nylon vest goes over everything...and might even have some neat little pockets to store equipment...like what we used to wear for PRESS.

Answer (score 4):

#### Nature Photographer at Work (Really!)

To put concerned bystanders at ease, you want to make sure they understand the situation. So the most effective message is likely to be a direct one.

Colorful jokes may work sometimes, but if people don't understand what's going on, they may feel compelled to verify.

I'd suggest having the same, direct message on a yard sign (or two) and on the back of a shirt or jacket. The more on-purpose it looks, the more folks will attend to the message.

Answer (score 2):

Take a leaf out of Terry Pratchett's book (or some of his books at least :) and just put up a little sign beside her that says:

**"I ate'nt dead"**

Answer (score 2):

What if she just don't let others see her by camouflaging herself. It might work in some places.

Comment: She could camouflage or otherwise hide herself. But if she doesn't do this perfectly, then it might just look like someone has tried to hide a body, making the problem worse.

Comment: Not entirely joking: perhaps a [ghillie suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghillie_suit)?

Comment: Sounds like a good way to get shot by a deer hunter.